# Testing in React/Redux - how to guarantee that state has been updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I'm writing tests for my new React app, part of my intention with this project is to fully understand this testing thing - it's been on my radar for a while but I haven't put it into production before.

Written a fair number of test so far that are using snapshots and other static & synchronous approaches.  This seems to work fine until now where I'm dealing with a setState -> expect(postFunctionState).toEqual(desiredState) situation and while I console.log my way through the flow and can see that setState() is being called and I can see the results in the browser, I can't seem to write a test that replicates the behaviour.

Here's the relevant code:

```
//Component (extracted):
export class CorsetCreator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      productName: '',
      productType: 'Overbust',
      enabled: false,
      created: false,
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleProductChange = this.handleProductChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleNameChange(e) {
    this.setState({ productName: e.target.value });
    this.handleChange.bind(this)(e);
  }

  handleProductChange(e) {
    this.setState({ productType: e.target.value });
    this.handleChange.bind(this)(e);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target.value === '') {
      this.setState({ enabled: false }); //User should not be able to submit an empty product name
      return;
    }

    const { corsets } = this.props.corsetGallery;
    if (!corsets) {
      this.forceUpdate();
      this.setState({ enabled: true }); //Point of this exercise is to guarantee unique combos of name&type.  If there are no pre-existing corsets then no need to test for uniqueness
      return;
    }

    const productType =
      e.target.value === 'Underbust' || e.target.value === 'Overbust'
        ? e.target.value
        : this.state.productType;
    const productName =
      e.target.value === 'Underbust' || e.target.value === 'Overbust'
        ? this.state
        : e.target.value;

    const filteredCorsets = corsets.filter(
      corset => corset.type === productType && corset.name === productName,
    );

    this.setState({
      enabled: !(filteredCorsets && filteredCorsets.length > 0),
    });
  }

//Test (extracted)
  it('handles statechanges correctly with a valid new corset', () => {
    const store = configureStore({}, browserHistory);

    const creator = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CorsetCreator />
      </Provider>,
    );

    const namebox = creator.find('NameBox').at(0);
    const nameBoxField = namebox.find('input').at(0);
    const submitbutton = creator.find('SubmitButton').at(0);

    creator.setState({ enabled: false });
    expect(submitbutton.props().enabled).toEqual(false);

    nameBoxField.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Test' } });
    creator.update();
    expect(creator.state().enabled).toEqual(true);
  });
```

Because setState is asynchronous I feel like some sort of callback or promise may be the solution here but I've tried both and can't seem to sort through the best way.   What is the best way to think about this type of scenario?

Comment: My only suspect is this line got executed `expect(submitbutton.props().enabled).toEqual(false);` before the state got updated and I think by executing the `expect` on the `setState`'s callback is the way to go, but you said that you've tested it

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my thinking as well.  To call the expect on the callback I had created a new class that extends the original component and overidden a "report" function, then created a nullop report in the original component code and wired set state to call that. This just failed to run.  Maybe I need to revisit that approach.

Comment: Edwin Harly, in the end my solution was to use a callback passed into the event proxy for simulate, requires a much smaller change to the component then I expected.  If you want to answer with someone hung about callbacks I'll accept that as well he best answer.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Remember React components are functions. In all their glory, they take in props and you receive an output of the `render()` function. Test the output.

If you have a variable in the state, chances are you're passing it to a child component or manipulating the visual output of the current component. Or said item in state would be useless :)

Testing the state is redundant, as it's like testing React itself.

A concern one normally raises is "But I'm showing/hiding that element by using `setState(...)`", or "I'm passing the state down into one of the children as a prop".

When writing tests, render the component. Simulate an action and check if the output of the render function has changed.

Take this component for example:

```
class TextWithClick extends React.Component {
  state={ count: 0 };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        value={this.state.count} {/* state passed down as props */}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TextWithClick/>
  , document.getElementById('root'))
```

It's simple. Clicking on the input field, increases the text it shows, which is a prop. Here are some test assertions:

```
// using enzyme
it("should increase the count", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<TextWithClick />);
  const input = wrapper.find("input").at(0);

  // test props
  input.simulate("click");
  expect(input.props().value).toEqual(1);

  input.simulate("click");
  expect(input.props().value).toEqual(2);

  input.simulate("click");
  expect(input.state().count).toEqual(3); // this tests React more than your component logic :)
});
```

Remember React components are functions. In all their glory, they take in props and you receive an output of the `render()` function. Test the output.

In the case of Redux, same thing. Testing state change is like testing Redux's connect() functionality. Mozilla uses a [real redux store to test their app](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/04/testing-strategies-for-react-and-redux/). I.e. test the final output.

I quote from the above link regarding testing a React/Redux app (can't seem to to multi-line blockquotes in SO:

- "We dispatch real Redux actions to test application state changes.  We test each component only once using shallow rendering.
- "We resist full DOM rendering (with mount()) as much as possible.
- "We test component integration by checking properties.
- "Static typing helps validate our component properties.
- "We simulate user events and make assertions about what action was dispatched.

A good article: [Testing React Component’s State](https://medium.com/@newyork.anthonyng/testing-react-components-state-b57bfc712b90) by Anthony Ng.

Comment: Hi Vik, I agree that's a great article and originally my assertion was expect(submitButton.props().enabled).toEqual(true).  Which is a better test.  However, while this works in the browser it doesn't seem to work in the console. I stepped away from the better test for a moment to see what was going on under the hood. when I log out progress I can see the call to setSate but it seems like the timing of setStste resolving is tripping me up. While your answer is correct I don't think it's quite enough.

Comment: I'd humbly say that you're missing the point of the state in React. And you're question is about React/Redux. Why are you doing a forceUpdate() before you set the state? Why use a forceUpdate at all?

Just to note, your question ended with "Because setState is asynchronous I feel like some sort of callback or promise may be the solution here but I've tried both and can't seem to sort through the best way. What is the best way to think about this type of scenario?". I won't be going through React's best practices, but you're missing the point of testing in React altogether to be honest.

Comment: You may be right... More details.  This tests whether the change handler has called setState correctly depending on a combination of props from the store and state in the component. I have left out a chunk of code for brevity.  In essence the store may contain an array of name/type tuples. In all cases the state field enabled is passed as a prop to the forms submit button component.  Given an empty/missing array as a prop and any value in the child NameBox the change handler should force a rerender of the SubmitButton with the prop enabled=true. Currently I use state to do that. I'm o

Comment: nly testing state right now because expect(SubmitButtin.props().enabled). toEqual (true) was failing and it looked from backtrace like the setState was being reached. Thought maybe a weird caching was happening.  Then I added creator.update() because again, setState is being called but no rerender seems to happen.

Comment: Honestly, if there were a way to extract handleChange and test it as a standalone that would be fine but it's a) gorilla/banana and b) probably too close to implementation.  Also, apologies for the rapid fire comments but lots in my head on this right now.  Very open to just being wrong at top of house in this as you say but my thinking is component contains interaction, that interaction generates a predictable set of results, I should be testing that the interaction generates the response.  (And yes I know the way the test is written right now it isn't doing exactly that but reasons as per ^)

Comment: After all of those earlier comments, I ended up exporting the changeHandler separately and testing it as a pure function in of itself. Not ideal but given that there doesn't seem to be a way to guarantee the timing I'll go with it.

Comment: I'm still quite curious about your solution. Could you make a webpackbin or some gists? I was also going through some gotchas when I first started testing React

Comment: Because I'm experimenting with Coveralls I had to put the project on github, so here's the two relevant files.  Index: https://github.com/crispen-smith/cinchedreact/blob/master/app/containers/CorsetCreator/index.js, and testing: https://github.com/crispen-smith/cinchedreact/blob/master/app/containers/CorsetCreator/tests/index.test.js . (still working through some of the final pieces of this)